# Calculation with relations

Tags: list-manipulation

I created set of realtions

```
A = {{a -> b, c -> d}}
```

and I want to check which number is bigger in these pairs. I have no idea how do it.

Comment: Does`Apply[Less, A, {2}]` or `Apply[Max, A, {2}]` do what you want?

Comment: You use symbols only. Without assigning numerical values it's impossible to tell which is bigger.

Comment: Yes , but this is just a example. A = {{1 -> 5, 9 -> 7}} I use Select to collecting from set A pairs where first number is smaller than second. But I don't know how I can compare elemets in pair

Comment: `Select[Less @@ # &] /@ {{1 -> 2, 4 -> 3}}`???

Comment: What is  it @@ ?

Comment: I got each elements

Comment: Its okay,thank you

Comment: But this Select[A,#[[1]]<#[[2]]&] is okay too

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {a -> 1, c -> 2}
MaximalBy[A, Last]
```